# SharePoint Access work offline / work online

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint

I want to programmatically 'work offline' then do code and return the tables back to 'work online' using VBA in access 2013

Comment: That sounds great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your solution is covered in this article.

[Link](https://accessexperts.com/blog/2011/12/08/how-to-work-offline-with-sharepoint-and-access-20102007/)

"Whenever you want to enter the offline mode, you only need to call ToggleOfflineMode"